# How to draw a special character of LaTeX fonts (cmr10.ttf) in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, latex, special-characters

### Summary

I'm developing a calculator app for iPhone and want to draw math expressions to UIView as same as LaTeX appearance.
So I use cmr10.ttf (LaTeX default) as a font for drawing but some characters were not shown.

### Test code and details

Here's my test code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];

    const int len = 4;
    Byte cstr[len];
    cstr[0] = 0x30; // 0
    cstr[1] = 0x00; // Capital Gamma
    cstr[2] = 0x41; // A
    cstr[3] = 0x61; // a
    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:(const void*)cstr length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    [str drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(10, 0) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"cmr10" size:40]];
}
```

I had expected to be shown "**0ΓAa**" to UIView but actually showed "**0Aa**" without a capital gamma.
According to CMR10 code table (see below), 0x00 means capital gamma. But in ASCII table, 0x00 means NUL control character. This may be why capital gamma characters were not shown.

Here's the code table of CMR10. General characters such as alphabets are same code as ASCII table but others are different.

[image]

(from page 18 of http://www.tug.org/texlive//devsrc/Master/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/encguide.pdf)

### Question

So I want to know is how to draw a character which character code is same as control character in ASCII.

### Additional information

- I used cmr10.ttf in the BaKoMa font package.
- I'm developing this calculator app on Xcode 4.6.1 and for iOS5 or higher devices.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to draw characters that have control character code by using `CGContextShowGlyphsAtPoint` and `CGFontGetGlyphWithGlyphName`.

Example:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

if (context) {

    CGFontRef font = CGFontCreateWithFontName(CFSTR("cmr10"));
    CGContextSetFont(context, font);
    CGContextSetFontSize(context, 40);
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMake(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, transform);

    const int len = 4;
    CGGlyph glyphs[len];
    glyphs[0] = CGFontGetGlyphWithGlyphName(font, CFSTR("Gamma"));
    glyphs[1] = CGFontGetGlyphWithGlyphName(font, CFSTR("Upsilon"));
    glyphs[2] = CGFontGetGlyphWithGlyphName(font, CFSTR("Theta"));
    glyphs[3] = CGFontGetGlyphWithGlyphName(font, CFSTR("fl"));

    CGContextShowGlyphsAtPoint(context, 0, 50, glyphs, len);
    CGFontRelease(font);
}
```

"Gamma" in second argument of `CGFontGetGlyphWithGlyphName` is the glyph name called 'post' (see http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=IWS-Chapter08#05931f9d). It is defined in cmr10.ttf file.

I used TTFEdit to find the glyph name.

1. Start TTFEdit.
2. File -> Open. Then select a TTF file and click Open.
3. Select *glyf* tab.
4. Find a character, then mouseover to it and hold for few seconds.
5. Glyph name will be shown as a tip.

Answer (score 1):

`drawAtPoint:` should handle all the encoding stuff transparently, so I would expect
the following to work:

```
NSString *str = @"0ΓAa";
[str drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(10, 0) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"cmr10" size:40]];
```

*Update:* I have now downloaded the font and tested the code. It really works.

*Update 2:* It does not work . But I have inspected the "cmr10.ttf" font with the "TTFdump" tool (from the [Microsoft Typography tools](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/tools/tools.aspx) page) and found the following:

The font contains a "cmap" table with platform ID = 3 and encoding ID = 1. According to http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/cmap.htm, this should be a mapping from Unicode to the glyph ids. But it isn't. For example, the Unicode U+00A1 is mapped to glyph id 19, which is the "Gamma" glyph. But the real Unicode for "Gamma" is U+0393.

So this

```
// 00A1 = Gamma, 00A8 = Upsilon, 00A3 = Theta, 00B0 = fl.
NSString *str = @"\u00A1\u00A8\u00A3\u00B0";
[str drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(10, 10) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"cmr10" size:40]];
```

actually displays the characters from the cmr10 font!

But I did not find out where this strange encoding comes from. So this is more of a
theoretical interest, and using the `CGFontGetGlyphWithGlyphName` as in Daiki's answer
is the better solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and testing :)
I tried that code but capital gamma was drawn with another font (not cmr10). "0", "A" and "a" was drawn with cmr10 correctly.

Comment: @DaikiKomatsuda: You are right, I hadn't noticed the difference. I will see if I can figure something out later, otherwise you have your working solution.

Comment: @DaikiKomatsuda: I have added some information to my answer. It does not solve the problem, but explains why the usual method does not work (wrong cmap encoding in TrueType font).

Comment: Your new method is so simple. I think this is also better for a few kinds of special characters. For many kinds of characters, my solutions could be easy to read. Thanks.